# Share photo by third applications on Android

Tags: android, android-intent

I use below code to get share applications:

```
PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
sharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(PhotoPath));
List<ResolveInfo> resolveInfo = packageManager.queryIntentActivities(sharingIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
```

I get all applications chooser as below:
[image]
And I use below code to launch application:
"one" means the selected ResolveInfo.

```
Intent MySharingIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
MySharingIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
MySharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(PhotoPath));
MySharingIntent.setPackage(one.activityInfo.packageName);
startActivity(MySharingIntent);
```

If I select the item "Photo" or "Google+".
It will pop below dialog:
[image]
But I want to launch application "Photo" directly.
Without the second select dialog.
How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding

`intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("packagename of the activity","classname.java"));`

But this is *not* recommended, you'll have to check first that "Photos" are indeed installed on the device.

Comment: I solve it by intent.setComponent(new ComponentName(one.activityInfo.packageName,one.activityInfo.name));